# How do I convert this if-else statement into a switch statement in java?

Tags: java

The prompt is:

> Convert the following if-else-if statement into a switch statement. Don’t rewrite the constants or variable definitions, just the if statement.
>
> ```
> final char BLT = 'b';
> final char VEGAN = 'v';
> final char TUNA = 't';
> final char ROAST_BEEF = 'r';
>
> double price;
> int sandwichType;
>
> System.out.println("Enter sandwich type: ");
>
> sandwichType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
>
> if (sandwichType == VEGAN || sandwichType == TUNA) {
>    price = 3.99;
> } else if (sandwichType == BLT) {
>    price = 4.19;
> } else if (sandwichType == ROAST_BEEF) {
>    price = 4.99;
> } else {
>    System.out.println("That's not a valid sandwich type.");
>    System.exit(0);    // This ends the program
> }
>
> System.out.println("Your total is is $" + (price*1.0825));
> ```

My current code is this:

```
switch (sandwichType) {
        case 1:System.out.println("The price is $" + (3.99*1.0825));
        case 2: System.out.println("The price is $" + (4.19*1.0825));
        case 3: System.out.println("The price is $" + (4.99*1.0825));
        break;
```

Comment: Just dont ;) is more versatile and more readable. And you can throw one construct out of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting breaks in between the switch cases. You also will want to use the char names of the different sandwiches instead of numbers. Finally, if none of the cases match the given sandwhichType, you'll want to have a default case, this would be essentially be your else statement from the previous code. The one tricky piece is the first case which accepts two different types which can be done by having a case followed by another case.

```
switch (sandwhichType)
{
        case VEGAN:
        case TUNA:
           price = 3.99;
           break;
        case BLT:
           price = 4.19;
           break;
        case ROAST_BEEF:
           price = 4.99;
           break;
        default:
           System.out.println("That's not a valid sandwich type.");
           System.exit(0);
           break;
}

System.out.println("Your total is is $" + (price*1.0825));
```

Comment: The local variable `price` may not have been initialized

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The cases should be options

```
case BLT:
```

You also need a default case

```
default:
    break;
```

And `break;` after *every* case.